# Openbox configuration doesn't take effect

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, openbox

I modified the `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` file on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (with Lubuntu/LXDE desktop environment) like below to disable window decorations:

```
<decor>no</decor>
# enable or disable window decorations
```

Then I ran `sudo openbox --reconfigure`, but even after reboot, the window decorations are not disabled. I wonder if I'm missing something.

Comment: Pretty sure the config file is just `rc.xml`, without the lubuntu- part in front of it.

Comment: @Dorian Copied the file as `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`, and modified the file and then ran `sudo openbox --reconfigure`, but still **no** change in window decorations

Comment: Can you post the entire rc.xml?  Just put it on something like pastebin.com and put the link here in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable all decorations on all windows, your rc.xml should have a structure like so:

```
<applications>
  <application class="*">
    <decor>no</decor>
  </application>
</applications>
```

Ensure any other settings you want to keep are there.  You could also simply add lines 2-4 in the code block above within the existing `<applications>`element, but make sure there are no other settings there that state `<decor>yes</decor>`.

Comment: Right, I think my [rc.xml](http://pastebin.com/jfcKLVbC) is not formatted properly:

Comment: Yes I figured that was probably the case, which is why I posted the answer.  Also make sure there are no blocks commented out with the `<!--` tags around them or those settings will be ignored.

Comment: It worked: I added line 2 to line 4 of your code **inside** the `<applications></applications>` element

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out :)